# How to change column attributes in GridView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a `GridView` that has 4 data fields and 1 hidden template field holding 2 buttons. I'm trying to programmatically set the template visibility to `true`, but the following doesn't work:

**aspx**

```
<asp:GridView ID="PendingView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnDataBound="CheckButtons">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="RID" visible="false" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ExpenseType" HeaderText="Expense Type" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="CurrentDate" HeaderText="Date" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Amount" HeaderText="Amount" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Details" HeaderText="Details" />
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="btnApprove" runat="server" text="Approve" Visible="false" />
                <asp:Button ID="btnDecline" runat="server" text="Decline" Visible="false"/>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

**aspx.cs**

```
//all works perfectly fine except last line
DataSet allInfo = new DataSet();
allInfo = GetData();
PendingView.DataSource = allInfo;
PendingView.DataBind();
PendingView.Columns[5].Visible = true; //doesn't work
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your template field is not hidden, the two buttons inside it are what's hidden. So of course setting the column visibility to `true` doesn't work. You need to change the visibility of the buttons inside.

It looks like you're trying to make it visible right at the beginning, so why are you hiding the buttons in the aspx page and then trying to make it visible in the code-behind? Simply make them visible in the aspx page by removing the `Visible="false"`:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnApprove" runat="server" text="Approve" />
<asp:Button ID="btnDecline" runat="server" text="Decline" />
```

If you really want to hide it in aspx and show it in the code-behind, then hide the template field itself in the aspx page:

```
<asp:TemplateField Visible="false">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="btnApprove" runat="server" text="Approve"  />
        <asp:Button ID="btnDecline" runat="server" text="Decline" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Then your code-behind will work as you have it in the question.

If you want to actually keep the aspx page as you have it in the question (with the buttons hidden), then you need to show the buttons, not the template, in the code-behind. The problem is that to access those buttons, you'll have to iterate through the rows. Something like this:

```
foreach(var row in == PendingView.Rows) {
    row.FindControl("btnApprove").Visible = true;
    row.FindControl("btnDecline").Visible = true;
}
```